# Editing Content Type Custom Forms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, content-type, custom-form

We have migrated MOSS 2007 sites to SharePoint 2010 using Database attach-detach method. 
Every list has 1-2 content types and each content type has its own New, Edit and Display forms. 

I tried opening these pages in SharePoint Designer 2010 but looks like there is no way of accessing these files. 
There is a **Forms** section on the **Content Type Settings** Page, and I can see the links, when I click on the link they change to textboxes. I wanted to check if there is a way to edit these files. Any pointers on how to create custom forms for Content Types without using VS would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can edit these files. 

I could reach to these files by using SharePoint Designer. 

File-> Pages ->Open (on the right pane)->Lists.

When a list is opened, we can see the custom forms for the content types and from there we can open these files.

[image: File->Open->Pages]

[image: List]